# SQL query to find 'fruit' that no-one loves

Tags: sql

Can someone help me out with how I can find the 'Fruit' that no-one loves?

```
Fruit      LoveIt    Name  
Apple        Y       John  
Apple        N       Mary  
Apple        Y       Stephen  
Pear         N       Lois  
Pear         N       Jo  
Pear         N       Fiona
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you help us out and show us what you tried and explain what specifically didn't work about that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using aggregation:

```
select fruit
from fruits
group by fruit
having count(case when LoveIt = 'Y' then 1 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant that doesn't rely on counting but stresses *thinking in sets* (relational algebra style, if you will): the fruits no one loves are all fruits but those that are loved by somebody:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.Fruit
FROM   fruits f

 EXCEPT

SELECT f.Fruit
FROM   fruits f
WHERE  f.LoveIt = 'Y'
```

`EXCEPT` is SQL's set difference operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

`select fruit, loveit, count(*)
  from survey
 group by 1,2
having loveit = 'N'
   and count(*) = 0;`

Answer (score -1):

Select distinct fruit from tab x where fruit not in (select fruit from tab where love it = 'Y')